# Google Reader OAuth mark as read

Tags: api, post, oauth, google-reader

I'm using Google Reader API (unofficial) and OAuth authentification. All GET requests work fine, but not POST ones (such as marking an entry as read) - they return 401 error without further explanation. I tried this in code (C#) and in [Google OAuth Playground](http://googlecodesamples.com/oauth_playground/index.php) and get the same 401 error. What exactly request should I send to Google Reader to mark an entry as read?

Comment: Can you post what you are sending now that gets the 401 error?

Comment: I send `a=user/-/state/com.google/read&ac=edit&i=tag:google.com,2005:reader/item/daef3c61fd4eaa89&T=//UNSYt0wcFmqNwotdcv6Qnw` as POST body and `OAuth oauth_consumer_key="xxxx", oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", oauth_signature="xxxx", oauth_timestamp="1313566485", oauth_nonce="xxxx", oauth_version="1.0", oauth_token="xxxx"` as value of Authorization header to URL https://www.google.com/reader/api/0/edit-tag.

Comment: Earlier I used login/password authentification, and the same POST request (of course, without Authorization header) worked well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is solved by using Google experimental OAuth2 authorization, which docs can be found at http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2.html . Self-implementing this protocol wasn't as difficult as I've thought =)